# Unable to import .py File created for excel sheet creation in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, xlsxwriter

I've created a Python file for Excel sheet creation :

**StoreOpenClose.py**

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Store_Open_Close.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.add_table('A1:H60')

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'ID ', bold) 
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Zomato Outlet Name ', bold)
worksheet.write(0, 2, 'Enable On Zomato (Yes/No) ', bold)
worksheet.write(0, 3, 'Is Taking Orders Active (Yes/No) ', bold) 
worksheet.write(0, 4, 'DistributionPointActive ', bold)
worksheet.write(0, 5, 'OnChannelPartnerActive ', bold)
worksheet.write(0, 6, 'IsTakingOrders ', bold)
worksheet.write(0, 7, 'Zomato Status (Open/Close) ', bold)

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 5)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 25)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 28)
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 21)
worksheet.set_column('F:F', 23)
worksheet.set_column('G:G', 14)
worksheet.set_column('H:H', 25)

worksheet.set_default_row(hide_unused_rows=True)


workbook.close()
```

Please can anyone suggest how to make it compatible to import to Robot Framework. As currently while importing it into Resources it is giving import error.

[image: .py file import error]

Comment: Would be good to provide Test Suite and StoreOpenClose.py filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

- Import is as a `Library` instead of `Resource`, and see the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module)
- Wrap Python library functionality into a function/functions
- Make sure that the Python code runs without errors
- Check that the path is correct

Comment: Importing as a library is even giving error.
I even tried to directly open my xls file using keyword - ***ExcelLibrary.Open Excel*** but its giving error as - ***Opens the Excel file from the path provided in the file name parameter. If the boolean useTempDir is set to true, depending on the operating system of the computer running the test the file will be opened in the Temp directory if the operating system is Windows or tmp directory if it is not.

FAIL NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented***

Comment: the python code that i shared is running fine and my excel is getting created

Comment: Then double-check the relative path. The `ExcelLibrary.Open Excel` is not related to the question at all.

Comment: yes the question states importing of the file. since it wasn't working for me so had tried with the keyword. Thanks for the replies I'll cross check with the relative path.

Comment: Also, you might need to wrap the library functionality into a function and then call the function as keyword in your RF code. That might do it.